# Jquery check/uncheck checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have an event listener that listens to a series of checkboxes, I am able to add a property when the box is checked, but when the box is unchecked I am not able to remove the property. what can be done to make it work properly?

so when i use this:
$(this).val(':checked'); then I get this

How do I remove the value=":checked"  ?

```
<script>
    $('.programs').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val(':checked') == "checked") {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $(this).val(':checked');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a Fiddle? Looks like this shouldn't even work at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check a checkbox with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Comment: `$(this).val(':checked')` should be `$(this).is(':checked')`

Comment: The click on a checkbox element, check/uncheck itself, what are trying to achieve?

Comment: Irvin, I am trying to remove the :checked value from the page when the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: Thanks Irvin, Gaurang Tandon answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
$('.programs').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).prop("value", "Some thing");
        // or $(this).next("label").value("Some thing");
    } else {
        $(this).prop("value", "Some other thing")
        // or $(this).next("label").value("Some other thing");
    }
});
```

Using [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) jQuery method. I assume you are trying to check whether an element is checked or not, and not change its state instead.

Comment: this just logs it to the console, I am setting the value and need to remove the value when it is unchecked

Comment: @jpavlov I edited my answer. First line, changes the property `value`, while the other changes the text visible on screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $('.programs').click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            console.log("checked");
        } else {
            console.log("Uncheked");
        }
    });
```